# Given a bilinear (or quadratic) form, how can you find the orthogonal of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ equipped with a symmetric bilinear form $B$. Let $W$ be a vector subspace of $V$. I know that we define the orthogonal complement $W^\bot$ to be

$$W^\bot=\left\{x\in V : B( x, y ) = 0 \mbox{ for all } y\in W \right\}\ . $$

Could you show me concretely how does one calculate the orthogonal complement of a vector space? For instance, let us take $W=\{(a,b,c,d)|a+b=0, c-2d=0\}$ vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ and $q$ the quadratic form such that $q(a,b,c,d)=2a^2-2ab+2bc+b^2+3c^2+d^2$.

Comment: Is $V = \Bbb R^4$ and $B$ the usual inner product?

Comment: You didn't define $B$; in any case it is possible to work with basis. Alternatively, it might simplify matter if you diagonalize $B$ (a common practice for quadratic space)

Comment: @IvoTerek Sorry, somehow I had deleted the end of the question. Now I've edited it.

Comment: One way is to use the Gram-Schmidt process.  Start with a basis for W, which you can make orthogonal, and extend to a basis of V.  Gram-Schmidt (in the right order) will make that basis orthogonal, preserving your orthogonal basis for W.  So the remainder of the basis wil be a basis for $W^\perp$.

Comment: @Kimball I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Okay, well another thing you can do is take a basis $w_1, w_2$ for $W$ and describe the set of vectors orthogonal to $w_1$ and $w_2$.  It's not hard to prove this is precisely $W^\perp$, and if you want a basis, it shouldn't be hard to find one (it will ahve dimension 2).